# glTexEnv returns inexplainable INVALID_OPERATION ERROR

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

**Problem:**

Right after "glTexEnvi( GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL_TRUE);" I got the GL ERROR #1282(INVALID_OPERATION).

Then when I consulted the OpenGL 2.1 Reference, it is said under glTexEnv that: GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glTexEnv is executed between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd. **But** this is not my circumstance, since I am using vertex array.

Here's part of my code:

```
void RBFS::render_pass1_point_sprites(Shader &shader1, int width, int height, float t)
{
 shader1.bind();

 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_texRBFData[0]);
  MyCheckErrorGL();
 }
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_texRBFData[1]);
  MyCheckErrorGL();
 }
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, m_texSDF);
  MyCheckErrorGL();
 }
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, m_texLabels[0]);
  MyCheckErrorGL();
 }
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, m_texLabels[1]);
  MyCheckErrorGL();
 } 
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_texHG);
  MyCheckErrorGL();
 }
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE9);{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texCircle);
  MyCheckErrorGL();
 }

 // upload t
 GLuint loc_t = my_glGetUniformLocation(shader1.id(), "tSlice");
 glUniform1f(loc_t, t);
 MyCheckErrorGL();

 // SET POINT_SPRITE
 glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);
        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);// so we can set different point size in VShader
 float sizes[2];
 glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, sizes);
 glPointParameterf(GL_POINT_SIZE_MIN, sizes[0]);
 glPointParameterf(GL_POINT_SIZE_MAX, sizes[1]);
 MyCheckErrorGL();
 glTexEnvi( GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL_TRUE);// means tex-coord iteration
 MyCheckErrorGL();
 glPointParameterfARB(GL_POINT_SPRITE_COORD_ORIGIN, GL_LOWER_LEFT);// set origin-y
 MyCheckErrorGL();
 glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
 MyCheckErrorGL();

 glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo_density);{

  glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();

  glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  MyCheckErrorGL();

  glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numRBFs);//3rd parameter: number of points
  MyCheckErrorGL();

  glDisable(GL_BLEND);
  glPopMatrix();
  glPopAttrib();
 }
 glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

 // turn off switches for PSprite
 glDisable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);
 glDisable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);

 MyCheckErrorGL();

 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE9);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);

 shader1.unbind();
 MyCheckErrorGL();
}
```

Since I am a green hand on OpenGL. If you have other advice on my code, plz don't hesitate to tell me.:-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your OpenGL device does not support POINT_SPRITE at all.

The GL 2.0 specification has integrated point sprite as a core feature. What GL version does your device support ?

Comment: Good question. Please post the result of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`.

Comment: That's only the digits; glGetString(GL_VERSION) should contain some more information (about your context type, specifically). As the subset of points features is deprecated, it's very relevant here whether you have a 3.3 compatibility profile or core profile context.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [glTexEnv reference page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml), it says :

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glTexEnv is executed between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd.

It also says this :

> GL_POINT_SPRITE and GL_COORD_REPLACE are available only if the GL version is 2.0 or greater.

Are you sure your card, or driver supports opengl 2.0?